# How do I add prompt entry to object and have it called back in another prompt?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, prompt

I'm making a color guessing game. I'm trying to have a prompt ask for the players name, and then have the players first and last name pop up on the next prompt before the game starts.

```
function user() {
    let player = {
        firstName: '',
        lastName: ''
    }

    player = prompt("To play enter your first and last name:");
    if (player === null) {
        alert("This game is cancelled.");
        return;
    } else {
        player.name = prompt("Thank you, let get started " + player.name + "!");
        runGame();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you're confusing variable names. You are assigning the result of the name to `player` variable, not `player.name`.

```js
function user() {
    let player = {
      // if we're reading the full name at once we should get rid of redundancy
      name: null
    }

    // here we assign the result of the prompt to name attribute of player object
    player.name = prompt("To play enter your first and last name:");
    // honestly I don't know what empty prompt returns so I would fall back to rejecting all falsey values
    if (!player.name) {
        alert("This game is cancelled.");
        return;
    } else {
        // Alert is definitely a better choice here as the player doesn't input any information
        alert("Thank you, let get started " + player.name + "!");
        runGame();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The prompt will return a string that must be *parsed* into a user's first and last names. `split` can do that.

The final prompt will block on user input. Presumably, this is the first move the player will make. I'd suggest moving that first input to the `runGame()` function, keeping the concerns of getting the player name and playing the game separated.

```
// just get a player object. (don't start the game)
function getUser() {
  let string = prompt("To play enter your first and last name:");
  if (!string) {
    alert("This game is cancelled.");
    return;
  }

  let names = string.split(' ');
  if (names.length < 2) {
    // handle a single name
  }

  let player = { firstName: names[0], lastName: names[1] };
  return player;
}

// start the game, given a player
function runGame(player) {
  let firstMove = prompt("Thank you, let get started " + player.firstName + "!");
  // run the game
}

let player = getUser();
if (player) runGame(player);
```